# Drop Down Menu bugs

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to do a drop down menu and I'm having two issues.

1. When I hover on links in the main nav bar (`about` and `connect`), the clickable area is only the words, not the entire area that the text occupies like 'works' and 'achievements.'
2. In the actual drop down menu, when I hover on the links, not the entire section of text that is occupied is selected.

I tried to fix it but only got it to highlight the right part of the area.

I have tried to add padding/margin but it didn't quite work.

This is my CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFFFF5;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav {
  width: 480px;
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: thin solid #000000;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.navText {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#nav ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
  font: 17px/17px sans-serif;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fffff5;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fffff5;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#nav ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fffff5;
  font: 13px sans-serif;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav ul li ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fffff5;
  font: 13px sans-serif;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #666;
  width: 150px;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="navText">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li>WORKS
      <ul>
        <li><a href="written.html">Written</a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="film.html">Film</a></li>
        <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ACHIEVEMENTS
      <ul>
        <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="acad.html">Academic</a></li>
        <li><a href="cca.html">Co-Curricular</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="connect.html" class="navText">CONNECT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My code can be previewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/zinctan/83jh28o4/1/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the reasons for the issues respectively:

1. You need to add padding to the link itself and not the `li`
   element.
2. Same issue as above, plus you need to add `width:100%` to the
   links so they can occupy the full width.

Another issue:
You didn't add `<a>` elements for the `li`'s that have dropdown inside it. You should add link as the other ones.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/83jh28o4/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFF5;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav {
 width: 480px;
 float: right;
 height: 30px;
 border-top: thin solid #000000;
 line-height: 0px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
.navText {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
}
#nav ul {
 text-align: left;
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
 font: 17px/17px sans-serif;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 background: #555;
 color: #fffff5;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
 background: #555;
 color: #fffff5;
}
#nav ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
 -transition: opacity 0.2s;
 width: 160px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
#nav ul li ul li {
 background: #555;
 display: block; 
 color: #fffff5;
 font: 13px sans-serif;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav ul li ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #555; 
 display: block; 
 color: #fffff5;
 font: 13px sans-serif;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
 #nav ul li ul li:hover {
background: #666;
}
#nav ul li ul li:hover a {
    background: #666;
}
</style>
```

```html
     <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <a href="about.html" class="navText"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
        <li>WORKS
         <ul>
       <li><a href="written.html">Written</a></li>
       <li><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></li>
         <li><a href="film.html">Film</a></li>
         <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
     </li>
        <li>ACHIEVEMENTS
        <ul>
       <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
         <li><a href="acad.html">Academic</a></li>
         <li><a href="cca.html">Co-Curricular</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
        <a href="connect.html" class="navText"><li>CONNECT</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**1: Change**

```
<li><a href="about.html" class="navText">ABOUT</a></li>
…
<li><a href="connect.html" class="navText">CONNECT</a></li>
```

**to**

```
<a href="about.html" class="navText"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
…
<a href="connect.html" class="navText"><li>CONNECT</li></a>
```

**2: Change**

CSS

```
#nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #666;
  width: 150px;
}
```

**to**

```
#nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}
```

and add

```
#nav ul li ul li:hover a {
  background: #666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the links:

```
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
}
```

Also the `<li>` elements in the same level need to have an `<a>` tag to work, like the follow:

```
<a href="#" class="navText">WORKS</a>
```

In this part of the code change the width to 140px (160 pixels minus 10 px of padding in both sides):

```
#nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    width: 140px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/6mpn8wpo/